# Specify the tmp path for Midnight Commander

Tags: mc

I have an Ubuntu running on a 250 go ~ hard drive.

When I'm copying 300 go + folder to another location, using `mc`, I can see that it creates a  tmp file located in `/tmp/mc-$USER` which getting bigger as far as the copy is processing until it reach the maximum and then `mc` is failing because no more space is available.

I have another drive with 2 To available space (`/media/$USER/myDisk`). Since I have more free space available in this disk, I wish I could specify to `mc` to use this disk instead in order to build the `mc-$USER` tmp file.

I'm wondering if to do so, I need to edit a setting from `mc`, maybe located in `~/.config/mc`

or if I should specify an argument when running `mc` like `mc --temp-path /media/$USER/myDisk/tmp`

Thanks for your help

Comment: I wouldn't expect `mc` to use so much temporary space just to copy files. How do you copy the files? select with "Insert" and F6? And how is it failing, do you get an error?

Comment: MC normally doesn't use temp files unless you work with archives. You could simply use `cp -a` or `rsync -a` instead.

Comment: I suspect that you press anything like 'Enter' when a huge zip/archive is selected.

Comment: OP copy 300 Gb from a 250 Gb disk, obviously some form of uncompression is done, hence need for temporary file.

Answer (score 4):

What you're looking for is

```bash
MC_TMPDIR=path mc
```

Answer (score 1):

For diving into `tgz` archives, Midnight Commander uses the path specified by the `TMPDIR` environment variable (Ubuntu `mc` package version 3:4.8.24-2ubuntu1).

It creates a subdirectory `mc-$USER` inside it.